# How to maintain the order of one column after changing it in the SELECT expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

When I order by `CreditRating`, it is in order of the description, so "Above Average" comes first. I would like to have the order

1. Superior
2. Excellent
3. Above average
4. etc.

```
select VendorID as FournisseurID,
        V.Name as NomFournisseur, 
        CreditRating = 
        case
            when CreditRating = '1' then 'Superior' 
            when CreditRating = '2' then 'Excellent' 
            when CreditRating = '3' then 'Above average' 
            when CreditRating = '4' then 'Average' 
            when CreditRating = '5' then 'Below average'
        end,             
        sum(TotalDue) as TotalDû
from Purchasing.ProductVendor PV
Order by CreditRating, V.Name
```

Comment: If `CreditRating` is an `int` data type then you should not use `''` for the numbers to compare to

Answer (score 0):

Just use a different name for your `CASE` expression and do the `ORDER BY` with the original column:

```
select V.VendorID as FournisseurID,
        V.Name as NomFournisseur, 
        case
            when V.CreditRating = '1' then 'Superior' 
            when V.CreditRating = '2' then 'Excellent' 
            when V.CreditRating = '3' then 'Above average' 
            when V.CreditRating = '4' then 'Average' 
            when V.CreditRating = '5' then 'Below average'
        end as CreditRatingText,             
        sum(V.TotalDue) as TotalDû
from Purchasing.ProductVendor V
order by V.CreditRating, V.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

**`ORDER BY` has complicated binding rules.**

If you specify a column with *no* table reference, it will be bound *first* to a matching column from the `SELECT`, rather than a column in the `FROM`. *Only* if no match is found are the columns in the `FROM` used.

Whereas if you specify a table reference, the original column in the `FROM` is *always* used.

[See this fiddle for the difference.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6eab166ee09b6420a8d4e670c8daad9)

So as a rule, if you *really* need to have the same name (which you should avoid for confusion's sake), then specify a table reference if you want the original column's sort

```sql
select VendorID as FournisseurID,
       V.Name as NomFournisseur, 
       CreditRating = 
        case CreditRating 
            when '1' then 'Superior' 
            when '2' then 'Excellent' 
            when '3' then 'Above average' 
            when '4' then 'Average' 
            when '5' then 'Below average'
        end,             
       sum(TotalDue) as TotalDû
from Purchasing.ProductVendor PV
GROUP BY PV.CreditRating, PV.Name, PV.VendorID
Order by PV.CreditRating, PV.Name
```